# Elastic search nest dynamic query with object initializer NEST 5.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, dynamic, nest, booleanquery

Hi I'm a new to elastic nest API and I'm using nest 5.x. I'm currently developing some kind of advanced search page so when user doesn't check a criteria i don't have to include that filter on my query. I'm trying to combine 2 queries under must operator with object initializer approach using nest. How to achieve it? I'm following the example on [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html]

> var secondSearchResponse = client.Search(new
>   SearchRequest {
>       Query = new TermQuery { Field = Field(p => p.Name), Value = "x" } &&
>               new TermQuery { Field = Field(p => p.Name), Value = "y" } });

But it doesnt work cause Field class doesnt accept type arguments.

I also tried to followed this approach from this topic
[[Nest Elastic - Building Dynamic Nested Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496476/nest-elastic-building-dynamic-nested-query])

here is my code

> ```
>     public HttpResponseMessage GetSearchResult([FromUri] SearchModels queries)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             ///
>             string result = string.Empty;
>             result += "queryfields + " + queries.queryfields == null ? string.Empty : queries.queryfields;
>             result += "datefrom + " + queries.datefrom == null ? string.Empty : queries.datefrom;
>             result += "dateto + " + queries.dateto == null ? string.Empty : queries.dateto;
>             result += "emitentype + " + queries.emitentype == null ? string.Empty : queries.emitentype;
>
>             QueryContainer andQuery = null;
>
>             //List<QueryContainer> QueryContainers = new List<QueryContainer>();
>
>             IDXNetAnnouncement record = new IDXNetAnnouncement
>             {
>                 kode_emiten = queries.kodeemiten
>             };
>
>             #region keyword
>             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queries.queryfields))
>             {
>                 var val = queries.queryfields;
>
>                 TermQuery tq = new TermQuery
>                 {
>                     Field = queries.queryfields,
>                     Value = val
>                 };
>
>                 if (andQuery == null)
>                     andQuery = tq;
>                 else
>                     andQuery &= tq;
>
>                 //QueryContainers.Add(tq);
>             }
>             #endregion keyword
>
>             #region kodeemiten
>             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queries.kodeemiten))
>             {
>                 var val = queries.kodeemiten;
>
>                 TermQuery tq = new TermQuery
>                 {
>                     Name = "kode_emiten",
>                     Field = record.kode_emiten,
>                     Value = val
>                 };
>
>                 if (andQuery == null)
>                     andQuery = tq;
>                 else
>                     andQuery &= tq;
>
>                 //QueryContainers.Add(tq);
>             }
>             #endregion            
>
>             #region date
>             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queries.datefrom) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queries.dateto))
>             {
>                 DateRangeQuery dq = new DateRangeQuery();
>                 dq.Name = "tglpengumuman";
>                 dq.LessThanOrEqualTo = DateMath.Anchored(queries.dateto);
>                 dq.GreaterThanOrEqualTo = DateMath.Anchored(queries.datefrom);
>                 dq.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
>
>                 if (andQuery == null)
>                     andQuery = dq;
>                 else
>                     andQuery &= dq;
>
>                 //QueryContainers.Add(dq);
>             }
>             #endregion keyword
>
>             var reqs = (ISearchResponse<IDXNetAnnouncement>)null;
>
>             if (andQuery != null)
>             {
>                 reqs = conn.client.Search<IDXNetAnnouncement>(s => s
>                         .AllIndices()
>                         .AllTypes()
>                         .From(queries.indexfrom)
>                         .Size(queries.pagesize)
>                         .Query(q => q.Bool(qb => qb.Must(m => m.MatchAll() && andQuery))));
>                 //var json = conn.client.Serializer.SerializeToString(reqs.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes);
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 reqs = conn.client.Search<IDXNetAnnouncement>(s => s
>                        .AllIndices()
>                        .AllTypes()
>                        .From(queries.indexfrom)
>                        .Size(queries.pagesize)
>                        .Query(m => m.MatchAll()));
>             }
>
>             //var reqstring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(conn.client.);
>             var reslts = this.conn.client.Serializer.SerializeToString(reqs,SerializationFormatting.Indented);
>
>             var resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
>             {
>                 Content = new StringContent(reslts)
>             };
>             resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
>             return resp;
>         }
>         catch (Exception e)
>         {
>             var resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
>             {
>                 Content = new StringContent(e.ToString())
>             };
>             resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
>             return resp;
>         }
>     }
> ```

But that returns zero result. How to achieve this? Thx anyway.

EDIT :

This is the params variabel definition. Its apoco model of search keywords

> ```
> public class SearchModels
> {
>     public string queryfields { get; set; }
>     public string datefrom { get; set; }
>     public string dateto { get; set; }
>     public string emitentype { get; set; }
>     public string kodeemiten { get; set; }
>     public string issuercode { get; set; }
>     public int indexfrom { get; set; }
>     public int pagesize { get; set; }
>
> }
> ```

IDXNetAnnouncement is a poco model of search result. Its actualy a document type which is stored on the elastic server

> ```
> public class IDXNetAnnouncement 
> {
>     public string perihalpengumuman { get; set; }
>     public string attachments { get; set; }
>     public string createddate { get; set; }
>     public bool efekemiten_spei { get; set; }
>     public string jmsxgroupid { get; set; }
>     public string tglpengumuman { get; set; }
>     public object errordescription { get; set; }
>     public string ESversion { get; set; }
>     public int oldfinalid { get; set; }
>     public bool efekemiten_etf { get; set; }
>     public object errorcode { get; set; }
>     public string jenisemiten { get; set; }
>     public int pkid { get; set; }
>     public string judulpengumuman { get; set; }
>     public string form_id { get; set; }
>     public bool efekemiten_eba { get; set; }
>     public string jenispengumuman { get; set; }
>     public string nopengumuman { get; set; }
>     public string kode_emiten { get; set; }
>     public string divisi { get; set; }
>     public string EStimestamp { get; set; }
>     public bool efekemiten_obligasi { get; set; }
>     public long finalid { get; set; }
>     public bool efekemiten_saham { get; set; }
>     public string kodedivisi { get; set; }
>     public string SearchTerms
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", judulpengumuman, kode_emiten, nopengumuman);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: please provide a complete succinct example that demonstrates the problem e.g. what is `queries`? what are its properties?

Comment: Its basicly a poco model of keywords i'll include the poco class on my question

Answer (score 2):

> But it doesnt work cause Field class doesnt accept type arguments.

You need to ensure that you include a [using static directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) for `Nest.Infer` i.e.

```
using static Nest.Infer;
```

with the rest of the using directives.

> .Query(q => q.Bool(qb => qb.Must(m => m.MatchAll() && andQuery))));

No need to wrap in a `Must()`, just do

```
.Query(q => q.MatchAll() && andQuery)
```

which will wrap both queries in a `bool` query `must` clause. You also don't need to `null` check `andQuery` because NEST is smart enough to not combine the two queries if either or both are `null`.

> ```
> if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queries.queryfields))
> {
>     var val = queries.queryfields;
>
>     TermQuery tq = new TermQuery
>     {
>         Field = queries.queryfields,
>         Value = val
>     };
>
>     if (andQuery == null)
>         andQuery = tq;
>     else
>         andQuery &= tq;
>
>     //QueryContainers.Add(tq);
> }
> ```

NEST has the concept of [conditionless queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/verbatim-and-strict-query-usage.html) so you don't need to check it `queries.queryfields` is null or empty, simply build the query and add it to `andQuery`. So it would become

```
var val = queries.queryfields;

andQuery &= new TermQuery
{
    Field = queries.queryfields,
    Value = val
};
```

#### Aside

All of the NEST documentation is generated from source code; you can trace back to the original source file by clicking on any **edit** link within the documentation. This will take you to a github page, [such as this one for bool queries](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/edit/5.x/docs/query-dsl/bool-dsl/bool-dsl.asciidoc). From here, the document contains an important note that links back to the [original source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Tests/QueryDsl/BoolDsl/BoolDsl.doc.cs).

Comment: Hi russ thanx for your advice regarding the null handling. Anyway i did have included the using static Nest.Infer; on my class. But still termquery not accepting type parameter. Is there any other using directive i should include?